# VC-Dimensions and PAC-learning of some specific certain class of classifiers

Tags: machine-learning, vc-dimension, pac-learning

I'm learning VC-dimensions and PAC-learnability right now and I need some help. I'm answering a practice exercise question that I'm prepping for an exam. So suppose we have some domain $\mathcal{X} = \mathbb{N}$ and $\mathcal{Y} = \{ 0,1 \}$. A hypothesis class $\mathcal{H}$:
$$\mathcal{H} = \{ h(x) \}$$
where $h \in \mathcal{X} \longrightarrow \mathcal{Y}$ and that $x \in \mathcal{X}$ for where $|\{ h(x)=1\}| \leq 1$. I forgot the special name for this special class of classifiers. But basically I need to do three things: (1) find  the VC-dimension of $\mathcal{H}$, (2) prove the $\mathcal{H}$ is PAC-learnable (without using the VC-dimension argument), and (3) prove/disprove that $\mathcal{H}$ is PAC-learnable when $\mathcal{X} = \mathbb{R}$ (without using the VC-dim arguments).

I think (1) is easy, the VC-dim would be 0 as it cannot shatter any single point. (2) is aight; I just need to show that the class of classifiers, through some $m$ or $\epsilon$ and $\delta$, satisfies the PAC-learning requirements. For (3) is where I'm not sure. A side of me thinks it's not PAC-learnable due to the domain space being larger (and now uncountably infinite). But I know some classifier classes that are infinite and yet PAC-learnable. So it may be possible that it is PAC-learnable (assuming that the VC-dim does not change when we changed our domain; but then again we can't use the VC-dim argument to show this). Any hints on how I can work on (3). I really am stuck, thanks so much!